# как редактировать запись в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf?

Tags: nginx

"Добавьте в /etc/nginx/nginx.conf следующую запись". Как это сделать в Ubuntu?

Comment: Текстовым редактором, nano, vi, mcedit под рутом

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в терминале вбей sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
и там уже по ситуации, что нужно то и пиши.